# Python. How to remove zeroes from a list in Python

Tags: python

```
X = [0,5,0,0,3,1,15,0,12]

for value in range(0,len(X)):

    if X[value] <= 0:
        del X[value]
        print(X)
print(X)
```

I run the code but then i get an error saying that the list is out of index range.
Can someone please help me out on how to correct this mistake

Comment: `[i for i in X if i != 0]`

Comment: You have your data structures mixed up- `del X[value]` is what you would use if you were accessing a dictionary, `X` is a list

Comment: Thanks. I recently started programming so i dont know the differences. But thanks for the help. I really appreciate it. I have to learn these stuff for my exam on Tuesday

Answer (score 44):

Try a list comprehension.

```
X = [0,5,0,0,3,1,15,0,12]
X = [i for i in X if i != 0]
```

Answer (score 12):

```
>>> X = [0,5,0,0,3,1,15,0,12]
>>> list(filter(lambda num: num != 0, X))
[5, 3, 1, 15, 12]
```

Comment: Thanks. And I have a question. I have  seen the function lambda on multiple questions. What does it actually do. Thanks

Comment: lambda functions are one line anonymous functions